# Adding Control Icon to XML Ribbon (Not Office)

Tags: xml, icons, ribbon

I have a program which has Office-like UI (2008(ish))
It has a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode"?>
<RIBBON StyDsc="Blue sea" MsgNum="1553">
  <TABS>
    <TAB TAB_ID="7000">
      <GROUPS>
        <GROUP GROUP_ID="7300" IMAGE_ID="xxxxx">
          <CONTROLS>
            <CONTROL CONTROL_ID="xxxxx" CONTROL_TYPE="1"/>
            ...
          </CONTROLS>
        </GROUP>
  ...
```

I added my line:

```
<CONTROL CONTROL_ID="xxxxx" CONTROL_TYPE="1" PROGRAM="MyProgram.exe"/>
```

It worked, but there is no icon, which I would like to add. How can I do that? Is it even possible? I tried something like 
image="myImage.png" or image="c:_full_path_\myImage.png"
but it didn't work.

Can you please help me with this?